# JS beginner seeking help on very short function

Tags: javascript

I hate to bug this awesome and experienced community with this type of newb question, so please pardon my newbishness.

I don't understand why this code, generates the error following the code, and I was hoping someone might be so helpful as to point out my syntax error... (just came back to JS after learning the basics of ruby, and now I am a little fuzzy w/ the JS):

```
var userprompt = function() {
    var num = prompt("Enter a number")
    if (num % 7 == 0) {
        console.log("Lucky, your number is divisiable by 7!");
    };
    else if (num % 2 == 0) {
        console.log("Your number is an even number!");
    };
    else {
        console.log("That number is not awesome.");
    };
};
```

The error (produced by Chrome JS console)

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token else
message: "Unexpected token else"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

Thanks for your time,
Patrick

**Edited code for Agrum's suggestion, and when run in Chrome JS Console, the only thing that happens is that the alert message pops up.

```
var userprompt = function() {
var num = prompt("Enter a number");
if (num % 7 == 0) {
console.log("Lucky, your number is divisiable by 7!")
}
else if (num % 2 == 0) {
console.log("Your number is an even number!")
}
else {
console.log("That number is not awesome.")
}
};

alert("This is a test");
```

Comment: Remove the semi colon (`;`) after the bracket of your `if`s

Comment: One pro-tip: Format your code with proper indenting, and it's much easier both for *you* as well as *others* to find and fix bugs.

Comment: Hope you know how to use the modulus expression %

Comment: EasyBB, I am curious if you think that your comment is a contribution to the discussion.  I'd prefer if you add some insight about the modulus expression (or whatever thing you're talking about) in the future... But, that is just personal preference.  Certainly you're not obligated, but I think it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need semicolons after an end-bracket for those ifs.

```
if(true) { console.log("something"); }
```

not

```
if(true) { console.log("something"); };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var userprompt = function() {
 var num = prompt("Enter a number");
 if (num % 7 == 0) {
  console.log("Lucky, your number is divisiable by 7!");
 }
 else if (num % 2 == 0) {
  console.log("Your number is an even number!");
 }
 else {
  console.log("That number is not awesome.");
 }
};
```

EDIT : There was also a semi colon missing after each instruction.

Comment: Thanks, I entered this code and now the console's only output is
"undefined"  I received this earlier.  I am curious what "undefined" is referring to... and why the prompt isn't popping up.

Comment: my assumption is that prompt can be displayed only after the window has been loaded. But this is an other question and I'm not sure of this answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I found one other problem in your code, let me edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your time, Agrum.  Sadly I am unable to get it to run.  I edited my question's code, and added an alert(); to test that the being executed properly.  Any ideas?